# Clear WebStorm Node options

Tags: node.js, jestjs, webstorm

When clicking run/debug within WebStorm it fails for Jest tests. The reason being the Node options in the jest configuration are set to `--watch --experimental-vm-modules` which fails.

I've tried clearing all my templates, resetting to factory settings and reinstalling WebStorm - but this still pre-populates.

The only solution I've found is to manually clear the Node options each time. I've no saved templates that it should be pulling these options from.

```
Node Options: --watch --experimental-vm-modules
```

Tried already:

- Reinstalling WebStorm
- Resetting defaulting settings in WebStorm
- Deleting all existing jest templates

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: In addition to @starball comment, be sure to take a look here: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

The `experimental-vm-modules` flag is auto-added if you have `type: module` in the `package.json` (see [WEB-52967](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52967/Automatically-add-experimental-vm-modules-to-Jest-for-ESM-projects)). But `--watch` is not normmally auto-added. Please check your **Jest** run configuration template in **Run > Edit Configurations, Edit configurations templates**